# PostgreSQL don't filter if results empty

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, conditional-statements

I'd like to know if it would be possible to get the following behavior with one query only.

Filter the results with `WHERE` but only apply the filter if the result isn't empty, like an optional `WHERE`.

For instance considering there is an users table and I want to retrieve all the users from Spain, but if there aren't any then I want all users (like the Where wouldn't be applied).

Instead of:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE country = sp

If result empty then

SELECT * FROM users
```

I wanted to do this behavior in one sql statement...is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select *
from users
where
    country = sp
    or not exists (select 1 from users where country = sp)
```

Comment: pretty elegant. i like that :)